# Как работать с данными, которые парсятся с сайта в программу?

Tags: python, html, парсер, pandas, dataframe

К примеру, нужно достать курс валюты с сайта:

```
http://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/
```

Использую для этого библиотеку Pandas, а именно метод:

```
df = pd.read_html(io="http://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/", decimal=',', thousands='.')
```

В итоге получаю DataFrame, состоящий из одного элемента, и не могу обратиться к его отдельным строкам и столбцам. Если выполнить `print(df[0])`, то в консоль будет выведена вся таблица целиком.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее

```
df = pd.read_html(io="http://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/", decimal=' ', thousands='.')[0]
```

а затем `df['Валюта']`
Это даст вам информацию о нужном столбце

Comment: Благодарю! Все получилось

Comment: А можете поподробней рассказать про [0] в конце метода? Если не затруднит

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на вопрос:

> Что я делаю не так?

Метод [pd.read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) всегда возвращает **список** фреймов, т.к. в общем случае на WEB странице может быть больше одной HTML таблицы.

Из документации:

> Read HTML tables into a **list of DataFrame objects**.

Поэтому просто выберите из результирующего списка нужную вам таблицу (DataFrame) по индексу.

Пример:

```
In [209]: dfs = pd.read_html(io="http://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/", decimal=',', thousands='.')

In [210]: type(dfs)
Out[210]: list

In [211]: len(dfs)
Out[211]: 1

In [212]: df = pd.read_html(io="http://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/", decimal=',', thousands='.')[0]

In [213]: type(df)
Out[213]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [214]: df.shape
Out[214]: (34, 5)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию! Теперь все стало намного понятней